# Facebook apps in 1 Firebase project

Tags: facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

In firebase project settings page, you can create new apps by clicking Add App button, each app has different App ID, Package name, Bundle ID, etc.

[image: Add App]

Question is: Why  is Add App button missing from Facebook section(Authentication > Sign-In Method > Facebook)?

Facebook lets you create multiple apps which have different App IDs and App Secrets

Answer (score -1):

You can only have 1 Facebook app linked to your Firebase Project.

Having multiple apps in a single Firebase Project doesn't mean you can have different products. Multiple apps means you can develop the same product for multiple platforms (Web, Android and iOS).

For example, let's say you're building a product named "stackoverflow". You'll name your Firebase Project "Stackoverflow". But now you need to develop it to Web, Android and iOS. You'll then create 3 different apps in the Firebase console. 
But all these apps will connect to a single Facebook app. Because they're all part of the Firebase Project named "Stackoverflow".